# Accord du participe passé : « Les plats que j'ai cuisinés »

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé, subordonnées

En français, écrit-on

> Les plats que j'ai cuisiné

ou

> Les plats que j'ai cuisinés ?

Quelle est la règle grammaticale sous-jacente ?

---

Should I write “*les plats que j'ai cuisiné*” or “*les plats que j'ai cuisiné**s***”? What is the underlying grammatical rule?

Comment: En effet.  Lire à ce sujet le premier paragraphe de cet article : [L’accord du participe passé en une seule règle](http://www.aide-doc.qc.ca/le.grammairien/ftp/pp1.pdf). Tout l'article est intéressant d'ailleurs pour ceux que le sujet intéresse.

Answer (score 10):

Il faut écrire « les plats que j'ai cuisinés » en raison de la règle suivante :

> Le participe passé conjugué avec *avoir* s’accorde avec le complément d’objet direct si ce complément se trouve placé avant le participe passé.

S'il n'y a pas de complément d'objet direct (COD), ou s'il est placé après le verbe, le participe passé est invariable.

Pour identifier le COD, il suffit de poser la question « quoi? » ou « qui? » après le verbe, en ayant pris soin de mettre le sujet avant le verbe.

Dans la phrase exemple, la question sera « j'ai cuisiné quoi? » La réponse sera « que » (mis pour *les plats*). Le COD est placé avant le verbe. Le participe passé s'accorde donc en genre et en nombre avec ce COD, qui est masculin et pluriel.

Inversement, si la phrase avait été « j'ai cuisiné(s) les plats », le participe passé serait invariable puisque le COD est placé après le participe.

---

You must write “*les plats que j'ai cuisiné**s***” because of the following rule: if a verb form uses the past participle with the auxiliary *avoir*, and there is a direct complement which comes before the past participle, then the participle agrees with the complement.

If there is no direct complement or there is one but it is located after the verb then the past participle is invariant.

To identify the direct complement, you can ask the question “what?” or “who?” after the verb, taking care to put the subject before the verb. In this example sentence, the question is “*j'ai cuisiné quoi ?*”. The answer is “*que*”, standing for “*les plats*”. The direct complement “*que*“ is before the verb “*cuisinés*”, therefore the past participle agrees with the direct complement. It is masculine plural so the ending is *-s*.

Conversely, if the sentence had been “*j'ai cuisiné les plats*”, then the past participle does not agree with anything since the direct complement is after the past participle.

Answer (score 2):

Si je me rappelle correctement ce qu'on m'appris il y a longtemps, on doit dire "Les plats que j'ai ***cuisinés***", puisque le complément précède le verbe.

Cela se passe normalement avec le verb auxiliaire "être", mais il est vrai avec "avoir" seulement dans ce cas.

Answer (score 1):

Le verbe s'accorde avec le complément direct lorsque celui-ci est placé avant le verbe. Plus d'information ici : https://regardsurlefrancais.com/2017/03/17/laccord-du-participe-passe-avec-avoir-demystifie/