# Comment accorder cette phrase

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Je bute sur cette phrase, personne dans mon entourage n'arrive à se mettre d'accord sur le bon accord :

Les missions sur **lesquel(le)s** j'ai **travaillé(es)** ont toujours
 **dépassé(es)** les attentes

Comment: Voir réponse sur l'accord du participe passé avec avoir [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/8387/358). *J'ai travaillé* n'a pas de COD et le COD de *ont dépassé* est placé après le erbe.

Comment: Mais ne s'agit-il pas ici d'un complément d'objet indirect ?  Dans ce cas quel est l'accord ?

Comment: Voir la réponse dans le lien que j'ai indiqué. Il y est dit quand accorder et comment trouver le COD.

Answer (score 3):

> Les missions sur lesquelles j'ai travaillé ont toujours dépassé les attentes.

Serait la phrase voulue.

> *Lesquelles*

Les missions (féminin pluriel).

> *J'ai travaillé ...*

Pas de complément direct, donc ne s'accorde pas.

> *Les missions ont dépassé* **quoi**?

*Les attentes*. Puisque le complément direct est après le verbe, il ne s'accorde pas.

Pour plus d'information, aller se référer à une grammaire de choix et aller voir les règles d'accord des participes passés avec *avoir*.

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/a/8387/358