# When to add feminine verb endings (accord du participe passé) ?

Tags: verbes

In the examples below...

Elle l'a appelée. 
Elle a ouvert la porte.

... how can you tell whether or not to add the extra e to the end of certain verbs making them feminine?

Using the examples, why is it that "appelée" is feminine, but "ouvert" is not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a matter of past participles being used with either the auxiliary verb "être" or "avoir" and I'm afraid it is a question that's been already asked. Check as carefully as you can; a question that's been already asked is never accepted again.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the question please?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8386/17649

Comment: There are lots - also consider [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29539/laccord-du-participe-passé-dans-les-temps-composés/29551#29551).

Answer (score 1):

The rules of past participle agreement is a hot topic.

In your cases, the rule is simple: the past participle used with the auxiliary verb **avoir** agree with its direct object **if** the direct object is located **before** the verb.

However, your first sentence has an extra difficulty. It might be written either:

> *Elle l'a appelé**e**.*

or:

> *Elle l'a appelé.*

Here the direct object is ***l'***. Some context is required to know if this object pronoun with an elided vowel refers to a feminine (*la*) or masculine (*le*) antecedent.

As *appelée* is used in you example, the antecedent is likely a woman:

> *Elle l'a appelée* (She called her)

Should the pronoun had referred to a man, that would have been:

> *Elle l'a appelé* (She called him)

As there is no neutral in French, *She called it* translation would use either *appelée* or *appelé* depending on the gender of the word behind **it**.

There is no issue with the second sentence, the direct object is after the verb, there is no agreement and the masculine is used:

> *Elle a ouvert la porte*

but:

> *Elle l'a ouvert**e***

Answer (score 0):

Une réponse non complète.

> Elle a appelé sa mère.

" sa mère " est le COD (complément d'objet direct = accusatif) du verbe a appelé (passé composé).

> Elle l'a appelée.

la=l' est le **pronom personnel** remplaçant le COD et venant avant le verbe conjugué (forme composée) => accord du participe passé.

Pareillement,

> Elle a ouvert la porte.

" la porte " est le COD du verbe a ouvert (passé composé).

> Elle l'a ouverte.

la=l' est le pronom personnel remplaçant le COD et venant avant le verbe conjugué => accord du participe passé.

ATTENTION

> Elle a téléphoné **à** sa mère.

" sa mère " est maintenant, le COI (complément d'objet indirect=datif) du verbe a téléphoné (passé composé).

> Elle lui a téléphoné.

**lui** est le pronom personnel qui remplace (à) sa mère => pas d'accord du participe passé !