# Accorder les verbes pronominaux dans les temps passé s

Tags: grammaire, accord

I know that for pronominal verb there are four categories of meanings, which are le sens absolu, le sens réfléchi, le sens réciproque et le sens passif.

And I know too COD or COI determines whether a pronominal verb should be accorded or not.

But how do we decide whether it should be accorded or not? And how do we do that exactly?

My examples are as below: 
Les vacances qu'il s'était octroyées.

Ils se sont octroyé une semaine de repos.

Merci d'avance !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accord du participe passé : « Les plats que j'ai cuisinés »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/accord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-les-plats-que-jai-cuisin%c3%a9s)

Comment: Pas vraiment d'accord avec le vote de fermeture. Les verbes pronominaux ont des règles d'accord assez particulières avec l'auxiliaire être, règles qui ont même évolué entre le moyen français, qui suivait la règle générale de l'accord avec le sujet, et le français moderne, qui indique l'accord avec le complément d'objet direct s'il est placé avant (le temps par contre, passé ou présent, importe peu). Cette nouvelle règle n'est d'ailleurs pas appliquée avec une grande régularité même par les grands auteurs, même tard au XXe siècle (je ne saurais me prononcer sur le XXIe).

Answer (score 1):

L'accord du passé composé with these verbs is one of the most complicated thing in French language and even natives always make mistakes!

Here is a little recap:

- *Elle s'est lavée* -> sens réfléchi, she took her own shower, so accord
- *Elle s'est lavé les mains* -> There is a COD after the verb so no accord
- *Les mains qu'elle s'est lavées* -> the COD is placed before so accord with COD

For the verbs with a sens réciproque, you also have to take into account the construction of the verb, if it is direct or with a preposition:

- *Ils se sont regardés* -> "regarder qqun", no preposition, so accord
- *Ils se sont parlé* -> "parler à qqun", verb wih preposition, so no accord

Comment: Merci c'est plutôt clair. l'une des règles les plus compliquées du Français, effectivement. Il y a une logique, mais on sent les règles édictées par des immortels, qui avait justement l'éternité pour réfléchir...

Answer (score 0):

--- sorry about my language ----

It's correct : Il s'était octroyé - quoi - ? The COD is before so you must agree

Ils se sont octroyé - quoi - ? une semaine de repos COD = after so you must agree